# Setting a Span's trace id in Brave vs. Sleuth

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-sleuth, brave

I'm looking for the proper way to set the trace-id for a Span in Brave. Pre-Brave we had:

`Span span = Span.builder().traceId(someLong).build();`

What's the brave equivalent? I have the following, but it's obviously not correct, as there's no way to set the Span's context explicitly.

`Span span = tracer.nextSpan().start();`
`span.context().toBuilder().traceId(someLong).build();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this `brave.Span span = tracer.nextSpan().name("name").traceId(someLong).start();`

Or more advance

```
brave.Span span = tracer.nextSpan().name("name").traceId(someLong);
try (SpanInScope ws = tracer.withSpanInScope(span.start())) {
  // do sth
} finally {
  span.finish();
}
```

Take look at [spring cloud sleuth migration guide](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-sleuth/wiki/Spring-Cloud-Sleuth-2.0-Migration-Guide) to catch all changes

Comment: `traceId()` isn't a setter.

Comment: You are correct. Root tracers generate 64-bit or 128-bit `traceId`s by default. Nevertheless, you can set `traceId` is via `TraceContext` at least for child traces as same as newly created ones

Answer (score 3):

You can use the TraceContext Builder to set your own TraceId.

```
    TraceContext traceContext = TraceContext.newBuilder().traceId(traceId).build();
    Span span =
            this.tracing.tracer()
                    .toSpan(traceContext)
                    .name("application.name"))
                    .start();
```

This is optional though; you could let the Tracer generate its own traceId  when you create a new Span :-

```
this.tracing.tracer().nextSpan().name("application.name").start();
```

Answer (score 3):

We can build up `TraceContext` first and then we can use this to create `TraceContextOrSamplingFlags` which can be then used to create `Span` as follws:

```
TraceContext traceContext = TraceContext.newBuilder()
                            .traceId(someTraceId)
                            .spanId(someSpanId)
                            .build();

Span span = tracer.nextSpan(TraceContextOrSamplingFlags.create(traceContext))
                            .name(someName).start();
```